# error dropping/removing server group: "test" in pgAdmin

Tags: pgadmin-4

So I just installed postgresSQL on my home computer to try and make a database, I followed the installed by clicking basically yes on everything but unselected stack builder since I don't wanna install any addons and just plan to make a quick database. But whenever it installed for some reason I didn't have anything already in the Server Group "Servers" whilst the person in the tutorial I followed had a database in there https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0n41UTkOBb0. I also couldn't add anything in it so I decided to make a new Server Group in pgAdmin (the only option I was allowed to click) and so I named it "test" after trying there I also couldn't add stuff so I tried to delete it, however now I got this error (version 15.2-1-windows) (pgAdmin 4)

`(sqlite3.OperationalError) no such column: server.hostaddr [SQL: SELECT server.id AS server_id, server.user_id AS server_user_id, server.servergroup_id AS server_servergroup_id, server.name AS server_name, server.host AS server_host, server.hostaddr AS server_hostaddr, server.port AS server_port, server.maintenance_db AS server_maintenance_db, server.username AS server_username, server.password AS server_password, server.save_password AS server_save_password, server.role AS server_role, server.ssl_mode AS server_ssl_mode, server.comment AS server_comment, server.discovery_id AS server_discovery_id, server.db_res AS server_db_res, server.passfile AS server_passfile, server.passexec_cmd AS server_passexec_cmd, server.passexec_expiration AS server_passexec_expiration, server.sslcert AS server_sslcert, server.sslkey AS server_sslkey, server.sslrootcert AS server_sslrootcert, server.sslcrl AS server_sslcrl, server.sslcompression AS server_sslcompression, server.bgcolor AS server_bgcolor, server.fgcolor AS server_fgcolor, server.service AS server_service, server.connect_timeout AS server_connect_timeout, server.use_ssh_tunnel AS server_use_ssh_tunnel, server.tunnel_host AS server_tunnel_host, server.tunnel_port AS server_tunnel_port, server.tunnel_username AS server_tunnel_username, server.tunnel_authentication AS server_tunnel_authentication, server.tunnel_identity_file AS server_tunnel_identity_file, server.tunnel_password AS server_tunnel_password, server.shared AS server_shared, server.kerberos_conn AS server_kerberos_conn, server.cloud_status AS server_cloud_status, servergroup_1.id AS servergroup_1_id, servergroup_1.user_id AS servergroup_1_user_id, servergroup_1.name AS servergroup_1_name FROM server LEFT OUTER JOIN servergroup AS servergroup_1 ON servergroup_1.id = server.servergroup_id WHERE server.servergroup_id = ? AND server.shared = 1] [parameters: (2,)] (Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/e3q8)`

I tried to right click it and clicked Remove Server Group and expected it to get removed but it didn't

Comment: That's clearly a SQLite error message, not a Postgres error message. And PostgreSQL has not UI, so there is nothing to click "Remove Server Group" in PostgreSQL

Comment: idk if postgreSQL and pgAdmin 4 are the same but I meant pgAdmin since it's basically the thing I got from installing postgreSQL

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem, two Server Groups that I couldn't delete in pgAdmin 4.
The only solution I found was to delete the pgAdmin's data.

**WARNING**: this will delete all the configurations of saved servers.

Go to **Help** -> **About pgAdmin4**, look for the variable `DATA_DIR` in the server configuration window. Go there and delete the file `pgadmin.db`.

Again, if you care about your pgAdmin configuration, you might want to dig deeper on the consequences. I didn't care and I just deleted.